# Highcharts.js keyboard navigation issue

Tags: highcharts

When navigating through a stacked bar chart with the keyboard the arrow keys are reversed so that left goes right and right goes left. Anyone else ran into this before?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue on some online editor with the steps how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/weytani/6atqvf7o/11/ not sure how to set this up so I can tab through on fiddle.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel fixed the fiddle and can confirm that the bug is reproducible.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel is there any way for you to at least verify that this is a bug?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. What are the steps to reproduce the bug?

Comment: Just tab into the chart and try to use the left and right arrows. You’ll notice they are reversed.

Comment: I just tested it and works fine on my device. Tested on the newest version of the Google Chrome and MacBook Pro 13-inch, 2019. Right arrow - moves the scrollbar to the right, left to the left - as it should be.

Comment: Not the scroll bar we are talking keyboard navigation. within the chart itself. Accessibility stuff. Like you tab into the chart and want to traverse the plot points with the arrow keys.

Comment: I appreciate your help on this just making sure we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: I was able to reproduce thie issue, the accessibility module is missing in your demo. Demo with the module: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f70knLsj/ After digging into I found that the `yAxis.reversedStacks` is responsible for it. Take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1a849hj6/

Comment: Well that is slightly embarrassing

Comment: davidjryan, if you think that it is a bug, please report it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can contact the core developers. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues